# Get MySQL result where every Nth row is needed item

Tags: mysql

I have one problem with mysql query, if it's possible.

Example: we have table with products, each product has field type, it could be "free" or "gold". When we search all products by keyword, we get results like

```
id | product_name | ... | type
---+--------------+-----+-----
1  | ...          | ... | free
2  | ...          | ... | gold
3  | ...          | ... | free
4  | ...          | ... | free
5  | ...          | ... | free
6  | ...          | ... | gold
7  | ...          | ... | free
8  | ...          | ... | free
9  | ...          | ... | gold
10 | ...          | ... | free
11 | ...          | ... | gold
12 | ...          | ... | free
13 | ...          | ... | free
14 | ...          | ... | gold
15 | ...          | ... | free
16 | ...          | ... | gold
17 | ...          | ... | free
18 | ...          | ... | free
19 | ...          | ... | free
```

The problem is: how to order this result to get each 4th row type "gold"

```
id | product_name | ... | type
---+--------------+-----+-----
1  | ...          | ... | free
3  | ...          | ... | free
4  | ...          | ... | free
2  | ...          | ... | gold
5  | ...          | ... | free
7  | ...          | ... | free
8  | ...          | ... | free
6  | ...          | ... | gold
10 | ...          | ... | free
12 | ...          | ... | free
13 | ...          | ... | free
9  | ...          | ... | gold
15 | ...          | ... | free
17 | ...          | ... | free
18 | ...          | ... | free
11 | ...          | ... | gold
19 | ...          | ... | free
14 | ...          | ... | gold
16 | ...          | ... | gold
```

I have no idea how to resolve it. Is it possible?

I know how to resolve it with PHP, but I need to know if I can do it with MySQL query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, product_name, type, r
FROM ( 
SELECT id, product_name, type,  
       IF((@r1+1) % 4 = 0, @r1:= @r1 + 2, @r1:= @r1 + 1) AS r
FROM mytable, (SELECT @r1:=0) AS var
WHERE type <> 'gold'
ORDER BY id ) t


UNION ALL

SELECT id, product_name, type,  r*4 AS r
FROM (
SELECT id, product_name, type,  
       @r2:= @r2+1 AS r
FROM mytable, (SELECT @r2:=0) AS var
WHERE type = 'gold' ) s
ORDER BY r
```

**Explanation:**

- The first part of the `UNION` retrieves all non-'gold' records and assigns `r` values equal to `1,2,3,5,6,7,9,..` to them.
- The second part retrieves all 'gold' records and assigns `r` values equal to `4,8,12,...` to them.
- `ORDER BY r` is applied to the whole set return by `UNION ALL` and enforces the required ordering.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b9d7/1)

Comment: thanks a lot, it's realy working. My first idea was how to assign every gold item to 4,8,12... as you write, but I had no thoughts of how to do it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

If you want "gold" on every fourth line, then enumerate the "gold" and enumerate everything else.  You can then combine the results and use arithmetic to get a "gold" on every fourth row:

```
select t.*
from ((select t.*, (@rng := @rng + 1) as rn
       from table t cross join
            (select @rng := 0) params
       where type = 'gold'
      ) union all
      (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1)
       from table t cross join
            (select @rn := 0) params
       where type <> 'gold'
      )
     ) t
order by (case when type = 'gold' then rn
               else 1 + floor((rn - 1) / 3)
          end),             -- get groups of 3 non-gold and 1 gold
         (type = 'gold') ,  -- put the gold last in the group
         id                 -- order the rest by id
```

Comment: +1, Your query is works correct too. Thank you! I've marked Giorgos answer first, because he was faster. It's good to see different approaches.